# Saving a 48.00 value to MySQL data type double it saves as 48

Tags: mysql, sql, floating-point

This might be a simple solution but its a headache to me from last couple of hours when i run this query

```
insert into payment set id ='13914', amount ='48.00', discount ='0.00',
     total ='48.00', fees ='2', charges ='', staus ='2'
```

The value `48.00` saves in db column as just `48`. db column type is double.

Comment: like i want it to save as 48.00 but it save in db as just 48

Comment: What's the problem? Are you expecting mysql to store the input format for you? Format your data *on output*. Also, [***DO NOT STORE CURRENCY IN FLOATS.***](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/14/currency-rounding-errors/) [Use DECIMAL.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

Comment: what is the solution ???

Comment: Does the question involve PHP or is this only a SQL question?

Comment: Is this the current homework assignment, this is the second one of these in the space of 20 minutes

Comment: store currency in decimal. store it as pennies

Comment: `DOUBLE` is IEEE754 binary64, in which the number `48.00` would be stored as `0x4048000000000000` which represents `0b110000.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` or `0d48.00000000000000`.  The precision (i.e. number of decimal digits) that you provided when inputting the data has been lost, and the full precision of the stored value is not shown (for convenience).  If you want to present the data in a particular format, you should do that yourself—e.g. if you need to preserve a particular degree of precision, you can apply that in your presentation layer.

Comment: Note however that values such as currency which need to be tracked to the same precision irrespective of magnitude are not well suited to floating point data formats like `DOUBLE`—better to use a fixed-point format like `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easily found in [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html):

> Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation dependencies.

Further [more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html):

> Attempts to treat floating-point values as exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation dependencies. The FLOAT and DOUBLE data types are subject to these issues. For DECIMAL columns, MySQL performs operations with a precision of 65 decimal digits, which should solve most common inaccuracy problems.

So rather use `DECIMAL`

Comment: Additionally, read the big red warning in [PHP's float docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), and I'm sure there's one for literally every other language with a float type.

Answer (score 8):

Your data is stored correctly.  48 == 48.00 when you use DOUBLE.

When you retrieve your data try

```
SELECT ROUND(amount,2) amount,
       ROUND(discount, 2) discount
  FROM payment
```

if you really have to see the `.00` at the end of your numbers.

And please, *please*, for the good of the profession and your future users, learn how floating point numbers work.

Comment: what if i dont have 48.00 instead i have 48.60 i need to store exact ammount to db

Comment: Did you try storing `48.60`? It most likely works correctly.  If you store `48.599999999` it will probably display as `48.60` when you use `ROUND(amount,2)`.

Comment: To call anything you store in a floating point variable *exact* is to deceive yourself. But it's not hard to get it close enough. As long as you're not trying to store Bill Gates's net worth with complete accuracy.

Comment: @AhmadSaad 48, 48.6, 48.32... no difference from database storage engine's point of view. It's how db stores data... if you want to round it up with query, use solution from Ollie's example, if you want to show it on your page such as 48.00 or 48.60  use some formatting function in language you use to build webpage (e.g. in PHP `number_format(48, 2)` returns 48.00; `number_format(48.6, 2)` = 48.60; `number_format(48.5999, 2)` = 48.60; etc.). As Ollie said, **learn how floating point numbers work**, is good point to start with.

Answer (score -2):

SELECT ROUND(amount,2) amount,
       ROUND(discount, 2) discount
  FROM payment

Comment: This answer is the same as the previous one.